# Obtener preguntas y respuestas de los formularios de Google con Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, scraping

Estoy tratando de raspar las preguntas y respuestas de [formularios Google cuyas urls están en un archivo csv](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kv9T1bSVhx2Gloy04Xd3AbECYlEhLJ4DiqTGREf1XlQ/edit?usp=sharing). Aquí hay un extracto:

`links_y_temas.csv`:

```
Link,Task
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB02GPXqkewVx35_ptzv0XO7GRZQGwyGE/edit?usp=sharing,Hotel ABC
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1VQpzX1GqsnI92J1trlP37v3GjVgNMp1h-1Rh_n8orII/edit?usp=sharing,Airline XYZ
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1z-qyHp7O4eTI848b6L8_vh59IJ-y0bFpAo--zwPKJxY/edit?usp=sharing,Airline XYZ
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1IoDbsif5qorINuUrF1Dl9iMtIdnAsTvVA3vMVsVHjy8/edit?usp=sharing,Airline XYZ
```

Trato de obtener las preguntas y respuestas de los cuestionarios/urls para meterlas en un archivo csv que se parece al siguiente:

```
pickle_file_name,id,question,answer_1,answer_2,answer_3,answer_4,answer_5,answer_6,answer_7,answer_8,answer_9,answer_10,answer_11,answer_12,answer_13,answer_14
applicantHotel_ABC_c,1,How do you feel about your next vacation after COVID-19?,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
applicantHotel_ABC_c,2,When do you think your next vacation can start?,In next 3 months,In next 6 months,In next 1 year,Only once COVID-19 is under control,Only once COVID-19 vaccine is developed,,,,,,,,,
applicantHotel_ABC_c,3,What are your preferences regarding medical treatment policy (with additional cost)?,Doctor's availability in hotel,Ventilator availability in hotel,Tie-ups with nearby hospitals,Availability of medical rooms with primary first aid care,,,,,,,,,,
applicantHotel_ABC_c,4,What is your preferences of complementary breakfast?,Buffet breakfast with social distancing,Buffet breakfast replaced with Ala-carte with limited options,Breakfast to be delivered in room with limited options (chargeable),Packaged breakfast only,,,,,,,,,,
```

Sin embargo, hay dos tipos de cuestionarios, los que se publican (los formularios de Google que enfrentamos en la vida real) y aquellos para los que tenemos acceso al backend. Si puedo hojear ambos tipos de cuestionarios, no puedo obtener las preguntas de las preguntas publicadas.

En efecto obtengo los siguientes tipos de exceptiones:

- `StaleElementReferenceException`: Esta excepción es difícil de entender. Parece que entra en juego cuando se lee un formulario de Google publicado. Puedes leer la primera pregunta y sus respuestas pero no el resto. Esto puede suceder si una operación de DOM que ocurre en la página está causando temporalmente que el elemento sea inaccesible. Para tener en cuenta estos casos, intentaré acceder al elemento varias veces en un bucle antes de lanzar finalmente una excepción.
- `UnexpectedAlertPresentException`: es porque parece que hay el boton para modificar el  `location:  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1HAMUvDpYiz-SpQpKwUOxyHqn3Be7OV9vLER3K5ltrxg/edit?usp=sharing UnexpectedAlertPresentException`
- `content_area.get_attribute("aria-label")`: Me siento como si estuviera repitiendo una y otra vez sobre la misma cosa.

¡Basta de hablar! Aquí está mi código que te permite obtener un poco más del 5% de los formularios de Google:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common import exceptions
import pickle


WDWTIME = 20
USER = 'yourmail@gmail.com' # ciertos google forms le requieren
PWD = "yourpassword"
def setup_chromedriver():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Programs\chromedriver.exe")
    """Algunos de los formularios de Google necesitan un acceso"""
    url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/'
    driver.get(url)
    # Encontrar el login
    login_field = WebDriverWait(driver, WDWTIME).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'identifierId')))
    login_field.send_keys(USER)
    # Haga clic en el botón siguiente
    driver.find_element_by_id('identifierNext').click()
    # Encontrar el campo de la contraseña
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(50)
    driver.set_script_timeout(50)
    password_field = WebDriverWait(driver, WDWTIME).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'password')))
    password_field = password_field.find_element_by_tag_name('input')
    password_field.send_keys(PWD)
    # Haz click sobre "next" button
    driver.find_element_by_id('passwordNext').click()
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
    driver.set_script_timeout(30)
    return driver


def load_data():
    df = pd.read_csv("research_assistant_intern_recruitment_an.csv")
    filter_col = ["Link"]
    return df, filter_col


def get_published_questionnaire():
    print("published questionnaire")
    questionnaire = {}
    btns = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".appsMaterialWizButtonEl")
    # el botón "Siguiente", *advertencia* "Solicitar acceso de edición" también está activado.
    next_btns = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("appsMaterialWizButtonPaperbuttonContent.exportButtonContent")
    if next_btns:
        next_btns[-1].click()
        next_btns = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("appsMaterialWizButtonPaperbuttonContent.exportButtonContent")
        while next_btns != []:
            containers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
                "freebirdFormviewerViewNumberedItemContainer"
            )
            len_containers = len(containers)
            for container in containers:
                len_containers -=1
                print("len_containers: ", len_containers)
                try:
                    question = container.find_element_by_class_name(
                        "freebirdFormviewerViewItemsItemItemTitle.exportItemTitle.freebirdCustomFont"
                    )
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    print("No question, NoSuchElementException")
                    continue
                except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException:
                    print("No question, StaleElementReferenceException")
                    continue

                responses = container.find_elements_by_class_name(
                    "docssharedWizToggleLabeledLabelText"
                )
                extracted_text = [response.text for response in responses]
                questionnaire[question.text] = extracted_text
                content_areas = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
                    "quantumWizTextinputSimpleinputInput.exportInput"
                )
                for content_area in content_areas:
                    skip = ["Document title", "Titre du document", "Adresse e-mail valide"]
                    if content_area.get_attribute("aria-label") in skip and not content_area.get_attribute("aria-label").isspace():
                        print("content_area.get_attribute(\"aria-label\"): ", content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"))
                    else:
                        print("content_area.get_attribute(\"aria-label\"): ", content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"))
                        content_area.send_keys("10102015")

                content_areas = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
                    "quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput.exportInput"
                )
                for content_area in content_areas:
                    if content_area.get_attribute("type") == "date" and not content_area.get_attribute("type").isspace():
                        condition = content_area.get_attribute("type")
                        if condition == "date":
                            content_area.send_keys("10102015")
                    elif content_area.get_attribute("max") and not content_area.get_attribute("max").isspace():
                        max = content_area.get_attribute("max")
                        content_area.send_keys(max)
                    elif content_area.get_attribute("aria-label") and not content_area.get_attribute("aria-label").isspace():
                        condition = content_area.get_attribute("aria-label")
                        print("content_area.get_attribute(\"aria-label\"): ", content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"))
                        if condition == "State (Two letter Abbreviation)":
                            content_area.send_keys("CA")
                        else:
                            content_area.send_keys("10102015")

                for content_area in content_areas:
                    skip = ["Document title", "Titre du document", "Adresse e-mail valide"]
                    if content_area.get_attribute("aria-label") in skip and not content_area.get_attribute("aria-label").isspace():
                        print("content_area.get_attribute(\"aria-label\"): ", content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"))
                    else:
                        print("content_area.get_attribute(\"aria-label\"): ", content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"))
                        content_area.send_keys("10102015")
                btns_answers = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupElContainer")
                for btn_answer in btns_answers:
                    try:
                        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', btn_answer)
                        btn_answer.click()
                    except ElementNotInteractableException:
                        pass
                    except exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException:
                        continue

                # long answers
                content_areas = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
                    "quantumWizTextinputPapertextareaInput.exportTextarea"
                )
                for content_area in content_areas:
                    content_area.send_keys("This restaurant is really good! Me and my boyfriend went there on our holiday \
                        we had dinner there at 3 of February food was 100% And the service vas 150% And i really want to thank "
                                           "\Asie for a really good service as for his coworkers. We highly recommended \
                                           this restaurant!")

                # check boxes
                btn_check_boxes = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
                    "docssharedWizToggleLabeledContainer.freebirdFormviewerViewItemsCheckboxContainer"
                )
                for btn_check_box in btn_check_boxes:
                    btn_check_box.click()
                    break
                # btn_check_box[-1].click()

                # # other weird check boxes
                btn_check_boxes = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
                    "docssharedWizToggleLabeledLabelText.exportLabel.freebirdFormviewerViewItemsCheckboxLabel"
                )
                for btn_check_box in btn_check_boxes:
                    btn_check_box.click()
                    break
                # btns[-1].click()
                next_btns = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
                    "appsMaterialWizButtonPaperbuttonContent.exportButtonContent")
                if next_btns != []:
                    next_btns[-1].click()
                    next_btns = []
                else:
                    continue

    print("questionnaire: ", questionnaire)
    return questionnaire


def get_backend_questionnaire():
    print("backend questionnaire")
    # a veces empezamos con algo que parece una página publicada con un botón "siguiente"
    # if driver.find_element_by_id('identifierNext'):
    #     driver.find_element_by_id('identifierNext').click()
    questionnaire = {}
    # Obtengo todas las cartas con preguntas y respuestas dentro de ellas
    containers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
        "freebirdFormeditorViewItemContentWrapper"
    )
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
    driver.set_script_timeout(30)
    # para cada carta
    for container in containers:
        try:
            question = container.find_element_by_css_selector(".exportTextarea[aria-label='Intitulé de la question']")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("NoSuchElementException in " + str(container))
            continue
        # Obtener las respuestas
        responses = container.find_elements_by_css_selector(
            ".quantumWizTextinputSimpleinputInput.exportInput"
        )
        extracted_responses = [response.get_attribute("data-initial-value") for response in responses]
        questionnaire[question.text] = extracted_responses

        driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
        driver.set_script_timeout(30)

    print("questionnaire backend: ", questionnaire)
    return questionnaire


def extract(driver, df, survey):
    count_questionnaires = 0
    result = []
    count_not_empty = 0.0
    print("survey: ", survey)
    for location, task in zip(df.Link, df.Task):
        if task == survey:
            print("location: ", location)
            questionnaire = {}
            if "docs.google.com" in str(location):
                count_questionnaires +=1.0
                driver.get(location)
                # test if it is a published version
                try:
                    ask_access_btn = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
                        "freebirdFormviewerViewNavigationHeaderButtonContent"
                        )
                except exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
                    print("UnexpectedAlertPresentException")
                    get_published_questionnaire
                if ask_access_btn:
                    questionnaire = get_published_questionnaire()
                else:
                    questionnaire = get_backend_questionnaire()
            if questionnaire not in [{}, {'': ''}]:
                count_not_empty += 1.0
            print(questionnaire)
            result.append({str(count_questionnaires): questionnaire})
            count_questionnaires += 1
    print("count_questionnaires: ", count_questionnaires)
    if count_questionnaires != 0:
        print("count_not_empty/count_questionnaires: ", count_not_empty/count_questionnaires)
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    """ Necesita acceder a la cuenta de Google para acceder a ciertos cuestionarios. También configurar chromedriver para que se ejecute en 
    estado sin cabeza """
    driver = setup_chromedriver()
    published_questionnaires = [] # tracking published ones
    """ Cargar CSV de los formularios de Google """
    df, columns = load_data()
    surveys = ['Hotel ABC', "Airline XYZ", "The Ministry of Tourism of France"]
    for survey in surveys:
        result = extract(driver, df, survey)
        survey = survey.replace(" ", "_")
        pickle_out = open("applicant" + survey + "_c.p", "wb")
        pickle.dump(result, pickle_out)
        pickle_out.close()
    print("published_questionnaires: ", published_questionnaires)
```

El output esta:

```
C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python3.7.exe C:/Users/antoi/Documents/Programming/Scraping/Python/new_scraper.py
survey:  Hotel ABC
location:  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB02GPXqkewVx35_ptzv0XO7GRZQGwyGE/edit?usp=sharing
backend questionnaire
NoSuchElementException in <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bb78e4006674ba0bd9384f86518d8b95", element="7271d9f5-478a-4dfc-8f9e-6d9248da5bcc")>
...
NoSuchElementException in <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bb78e4006674ba0bd9384f86518d8b95", element="3ff21bcf-6e8d-4b88-b64d-10cf5a11b18f")>
NoSuchElementException in <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bb78e4006674ba0bd9384f86518d8b95", element="16e5fa0b-3502-4ab7-a7f7-a47b1b8fa388")>
NoSuchElementException in <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bb78e4006674ba0bd9384f86518d8b95", element="fdc1bafb-51c9-4cc7-8f43-675ea9061338")>
questionnaire backend:  {'How do you feel about your next vacation after COVID-19?': [], 'When do you think your next vacation can start?': ['In next 3 months', 'In next 6 months', 'In next 1 year', 'Only once COVID-19 is under control', 'Only once COVID-19 vaccine is developed', ''],  ... , 'Education Level': ['No higher education', 'Diploma', "Bachelor's", "Master's", 'PhD', "Other's", ''], 'Annual Income': ['< £ 30,000', '£ 30,000 to £ 50,000', '£ 50,000 to £ 80,000', '£ 80,000 to £ 120,000', '> £ 120,000', ''], 'Feedback / Comments': [''], 'Email (Optional)': ['']}
location:  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1_iRBtfJANF5MGWqoIMQUxBdeuAa4ePMltdIsVRmdY5Y/edit?usp=sharing
published questionnaire
len_containers:  9
No question, NoSuchElementException
len_containers:  8
content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"):  Other response
content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"):  Other response
len_containers:  7
No question, StaleElementReferenceException
len_containers:  6
No question, StaleElementReferenceException
len_containers:  5
No question, StaleElementReferenceException
len_containers:  4
No question, StaleElementReferenceException
len_containers:  3
No question, StaleElementReferenceException
len_containers:  2
No question, StaleElementReferenceException
len_containers:  1
No question, StaleElementReferenceException
len_containers:  0
No question, StaleElementReferenceException
questionnaire:  {'Age': ['Under 18', '18-24', '25-34', '35-44', '45-54', 'Over 55']}
{'Age': ['Under 18', '18-24', '25-34', '35-44', '45-54', 'Over 55']}
location:  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1j0nk_Oo-_pfJBM4UcWITDPXT97-qX5mZpb3uVyKS3CA/edit?usp=sharing
published questionnaire
len_containers:  13
No question, NoSuchElementException
len_containers:  12
content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"):  Other response
content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"):  Other response
content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"):  Other response
len_containers :  ...
...
content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"):  Other response
content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"):  Other response
content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"):  Other response
len_containers:  0
content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"):  Other response
content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"):  Other response
content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"):  Other response
questionnaire:  {'On average, how many times per year do you travel for 2 days or more? *': ['1 to 2', '3 to 4', '5 or more'], ... , 'What are your expectations from the accommodations’ Pinterest page? (Please select all that apply) *': ['See pictures of customer service staff', 'See pictures of staff in general', 'See pictures of the destination', 'See pictures of all the types of rooms', 'See pictures of services available', 'See pictures that are not on the hotel’s website', "I don't have a Pinterest account", "I don't use Pinterest for these purposes"]}
location:  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1kq5dhHvftF6tWmRk_7cG4H0Mkzr6xnUhpTV0j2xIYeE/edit?usp=sharing
UnexpectedAlertPresentException
published questionnaire
len_containers:  13
No question, NoSuchElementException
len_containers:  12
content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"):  Other response
content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"):  Other response
content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"):  Other response
len_containers:  11
...
len_containers:  1
content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"):  Other response
content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"):  Other response
content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"):  Other response
len_containers:  0
content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"):  Other response
content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"):  Other response
content_area.get_attribute("aria-label"):  Other response
questionnaire:  {'On average, how many times per year do you travel for 2 days or more? *': ['1 to 2', '3 to 4', '5 or more'],  ... 'What are your expectations from the accommodations’ Pinterest page? (Please select all that apply) *': ['See pictures of customer service staff', 'See pictures of staff in general', 'See pictures of the destination', 'See pictures of all the types of rooms', 'See pictures of services available', 'See pictures that are not on the hotel’s website', "I don't have a Pinterest account", "I don't use Pinterest for these purposes"]}
location:  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1IFqdsm9yO8h17JsJPN4c84vpQP06PxIquWfTmRN-TVw/edit?usp=sharing
```

Así que parece que estamos perdidos en un bucle...

Comment: La primera mitad del planteo me resulta confusa. Podrías ser un poco más específico?

Comment: @Mateo ¡Claro! Cada uno de los enlaces en el csv `links_y_temas.csv` lleva a un cuestionario de Google. Me gustaría tener las preguntas y respuestas de cada uno de estos cuestionarios en un archivo csv. ¡Claro! Cada uno de los enlaces en el csv "links_y_temas.csv" lleva a un cuestionario de Google. Me gustaría tener las preguntas y respuestas de cada uno de estos cuestionarios en un archivo csv. ¿Me las arreglé para ser más claro?

Comment: Ok, podrías incluir los errores completos?

Comment: @Mateo Sí, aquí están. No hay ningún error porque estoy haciendo `try-catch`.

Comment: Me gustaría ayudarte pero habría que reescribir una parte del código que no es poca y pues, tengo tareas como todo estudiante. Quiero comentarte que algunos selectores que usas, son específicos de un idioma como por ejemplo: `aria-label='Intitulé de la question'` Viendo que está en francés, deduzco que probablemente se deba a que eres de dicha habla. Yo hablo español, así que esa parte de código estará rota para mí. Sobre selectores, por alguna razón la cuál desconozco, a mí me daba error con la función para buscarlos por clase y con el de css no.

Comment: @Mateo No hay problema, trataré de poner el cromo en español y adaptaré mi código en consecuencia. Por suerte, sólo son unas pocas líneas de código. Sí, ¿no tienes un problema con los selectores css? ¿Te refieres a los contenedores? ¿Cómo lo haces?

Comment: Me refiero a que `find_elements_by_class_name()` en algunas ocasiones no me funcionó o me daba errores, entonces usé `find_elements_by_css_selector()` y este si que funcionó. Además puede ser simple y más fácil de evitar errores de sintaxis de selector ya que funciona igual a `document.querySelectorAll()` de javascript y puedes darte la libertad de usar el mismo selector en la consola del navegador y corroborar la existencia de elementos que correspondan a dicho selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En cada formulario hay una variable javascript que contiene todas las preguntas y las respuestas asociadas. Beautifulsoup parece ser una mejor opción que Selenium para este caso. Es más fácil obtener las preguntas y no necesitas navegar por los elementos del documento.

```
def extract_script(soup):
    """Extracts javascript var for all questions.
    Seems to be an easier way to get the questions
    without having to nagivate selenium"""
    scripts = soup.find_all('script')
    pattern = re.compile('LOAD_DATA_ = (.*?);')
    data_position = 0
    for i, script in enumerate(scripts):
        if "LOAD_DATA_ =" in str(script.contents):
            data_position = i
    text = scripts[data_position].contents
    return text[0]

response = req.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
```

Comment: Las respuestas también? La última vez que hurgué alguna variable como esa no encontré ninguna. Tal vez sea posible en ciertos formularios.

Comment: @Mateo Las respuestas tambien. Es asombroso lo mucho que estaba allí, escondido a plena vista.